# node.js production applicaiton does not allow file streaming by php application

Tags: node.js

I have two applications:-

> 1.node.js express application

-This application holds an image in public/filename.jpeg

-in development environment ie :- NODE_ENV=development node ./bin/www .The image is served successfully by node.js and downloaded by php application.

-In production environment ie :-NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www .
The image is not serving successfully from node.js,hence zero bytes downloaded by php application.

> 2.Php application:-

```
-This works ok if above express application is set to development environment.
```

=>Is there a way to allow files in node.js public folder to be downloaded by other application while in production mode since in development mode it works fine ?

Comment: My guess your problem is not related with Node.js nor PHP but your prod server

Comment: Are you allowing the user that's executing PHP/Node read access to said folder in the production server?

Comment: Giving direct access to file system in public node folder is not a good idea. Exposing these files via nodejs is way better. That way at least you get just node process to hold a handle on these files.

Comment: @MarceloFilho I have tested in my local machine and production server and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc the php user resides in a different server from the node server.

Comment: @matcheek This means that i have to write code that serves files from the public directory right ?

Comment: I meant that you could avoid having two (or more) processes from different web frameworks fighting over the same file handles if you expose these resources via web server and prohibit other processes, php or anything else, from accessing it directly on the file system.